# Update item for Number field is not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am trying updating the current list column (Item Quantity field).
I am using update list item. If the both IDs match, return quantity.
However, getting this error: Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type.

The values are not empty. But if I use lookup column, it retrieves the value. However, I have to use the workflow.

Kindly assist.

Error code:
[image]

In the update list item, after adding the quantity item, I am getting errors. Before that, it ran successfully.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Column type(numbers) of the main list - merged svp and list getting data from - item copy 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you place your code in here so we can see what you are doing?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have added the images in my question. Kindly refer up.

Comment: I believe your ownID field is integer not double? Why you "return field as" Double?

Comment: I think [@Mark](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/22423/mark-l) is correct.  Match you data types and that shoudl fix it.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it